# Spring JMS ActiveMQ - unable to get multiple consumers to process concurrently

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I am new to using JMS/ActiveMQ and I have a Spring/Hibernate application that is picking up messages from a Queue in ActiveMQ and processing these messages for persistence. Since the messages take a while to process and persist, I configured my DefaultMessageListenerContainer to have multiple consumers(eg. 5-10) so multiple messages can be worked on concurrently. I've looked at alot of the ActiveMQ and Spring API docs and I thought all I should need to do is set either maxConcurrentConsumers to 10 + set concurrentConsumers to 5 OR set concurrency to 5-10 on DefaultMessageListenerContainer. Once I did that, I can see from ActiveMQ's built-in console that my queue indeed have 5 consumer. But when I drop 10 or 100 messages on the queue, the processing seems to be single threaded and I added a log line to print the thread ID and it seems to be the same thread ID processing all the request sequentially. From ActiveMQ's Queues page on the console, I click the Browse Active Consumer link to look at what's happening and it looks like one consumer has all 100 messages pending and nothing for the other 4.

I did some research, found this article from Spring (http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?61170-Messages-missed-using-DefaultMessageListenerContainer) and added a prefetch policy with a value of 2 thinking every consumer is signing themselves up for 1000 messages. Now when I send another batch of messages, one consumer will have 2-3 messages pending but the other 4 consumers remain idle and again everything is processed sequentially eventually by that one consumer. At this point I thought maybe it's something I am misconfiguring on the ActiveMQ broker. I read in the docs that the default dispatch policy is a round robin strategy but I saw a setting called constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy set to 1000 in my activemq.xml and tried setting that to a very low number(eg. 2) thinking it controlled how many messages the broker sent to a consumer at a time but that still didn't do anything. Hopefully someone can point out what I am doing wrong, I've posted my spring config below and I really haven't touched the activemq.xml at all other than trying that one setting(constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy). I am using ActiveMQ 5.8.

```
<bean id="importRedeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
    <property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="15000" />
    <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="-1" />
    <property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="true" />
    <property name="backOffMultiplier" value="2" />
</bean>

<bean id="importPrefetchPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy">
    <property name="all" value="2"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="importConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="${import.queue.url}"/>
    <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="importRedeliveryPolicy" />
    <property name="prefetchPolicy" ref="importPrefetchPolicy"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="importQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="${import.queue.name}" />
</bean>

<bean id="importListener" class="com.mycompany.ImportQueueListener" >
    <property name="importService" ref="importService"></property>
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="importJmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
   <property name="connectionFactory" ref="importConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="destination" ref="importQueue" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="importListener" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="10"></property>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="5"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to replace your `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` with a pool :

```
<bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" destroy method="stop">
<property name="connectionFactory">
  <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL">
      <value>tcp://localhost:61616</value>
      </property>
   </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="myJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
   <property name="connectionFactory">
    <ref local="jmsFactory"/>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd">




 <!--  <bean class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" id="destination">  
     <constructor-arg value="TEST.Q1"></constructor-arg>  
  </bean>-->

  <bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic">
    <constructor-arg value="TOPIC_NAME" />
  </bean>



 <bean class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate" id="producerTemplate">
  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
   <property name="defaultDestination" ref="destination"/>
 </bean>  

 <!--ActiveMq broker URL configured here-->
   <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" id="connectionFactory" >
        <property name="brokerURL">
          <value>tcp://localhost:61616</value>
        </property>
   </bean>  

    <!--producer configured here-->

   <bean class="Producer" id="simpleMessageProducer">  
       <property name="jmsTemplate" ref="producerTemplate"></property>  
   </bean> 


    <!--listeners configured here-->

     <bean class="Consumer" id="simpleMessageListener">  

      </bean>  
     <bean class="ConsumerSecond" id="simpleMessageListenerSecond">   </bean> 



     <bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" id="jmsContainer"> 
     <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"></property>  
     <property name="destination" ref="destination"></property>  
     <property name="messageListener" ref="simpleMessageListener"></property>  


    </bean> 
     <bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" id="jmsContainer1"> 
     <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"></property>  
     <property name="destination" ref="destination"></property>
     <property name="messageListener" ref="simpleMessageListenerSecond"></property>

    </bean>  





</beans>
```

Comment: use with above code for configure multiple listeners

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Those types of things should be placed in the answer itself, instead of comments -- they're only meant for clarifications to a post. Thanks!